# HDD 100% usage, 4000ms response time,3-7mb/s transfer rate after moving My pictures, My documents to it

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I did a fresh install of Windows 10 on a new SSD (480gb) and put the old HDD (1tb) with a caddy into the optical drive slot of my laptop (Lenovo B51-80). I reformatted my HDD to use as a storage drive and everything ran at a respectable speed until I tried to relocate My Documents, My Pictures, My Videos, Downloads from the SSD to the HDD.

Suddenly write speeds have crashed drastically and a 2GB file will take 30 minutes to completely transfer if it doesn't remain stuck at 99%.

How can I remedy this? Thank you!

HDD performance from yesterday when it was the main drive with the OS.
[image]

HDD performance from today when it's the storage drive, after I tried to migrate those folders.
[image]

**Update**
Post-format write speed of the same HDD is more or less the same. So perhaps this is just the transfer cap of the HDD being on a caddy. However I would really like to salavage some speed- is there any way?

[image]

More images:
[image]

Comment: Any SMART errors reported on the drive? Did you use the same SATA cable? What filesystem did you format with? I assume `NTFS`?

Comment: CMD and Crystal Disk Info show none. I've also tried defragmenting

Comment: What about my other questions?

Comment: You edited them in after my response so I hadn't seen them. There is no cable involved, as far as I understand they plug into the socket, it's on a laptop.. Yes NTFS

Comment: Have you let it work after copying for at least 48 hours? Most likely Windows is indexing right now.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, Do you mean I show leave the computer turned on for 48 hours to allow this to complete in the background?

Answer (score 1):

1) https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/b51-80_hmm_en_20150911.pdf  shows your factory's HDD is SATA-III, but IIRC the optical drive interface is SATA-II. That cuts the ceiling of interface speed in half, so it's not surprising the HDD now runs slower in that caddy.

2) HDD speed is adversely affected by fragmentation, so please defragment it. (Don't defrag your SSD ! ).

3) HDD speed also decreases as the drive fills up, but if you need it on your drive, you need it on your drive.

Comment: Thanks! So I cannot find the information about the optical drive myself. I have defragmented it once and the drive is empty but still slow. At this point my USB 3.0 hard drive has faster transfer speeds than this drive.

Comment: To find the interface class and speed of the drive bay connection normally used for optical would require contacting Lenovo support, as that spec was not in your HW manual (I checked).